# Is converting RTF to HTML ever a good idea?

Tags: html, rtf, richtext

I've got a problem - our flagship product has a text field in which there is rich text formatting. Basically it uses the standard Windows Richedit control, and the output (saved in the DB) is in RTF format. I'm writing a web frontent for the same DB, and I need to display this text on a webpage (it's the "product description" field).

Luckily images cannot be pasted into it, so that's one major problem avoided, but for the rest... there are a few RTF ==> HTML convertors out there, but I'm afraid how good will the results be.

Alternatively this field is new and hasn't yet made it into production (or into testing for that matter), so we could still change it to HTML, but... the flagship product is written in Delphi 5, and I cannot find a good wysiwyg HTML editor for it (aside from embedding a browser control with CKEditor or something similar).

And attaching a RTF ==> HTML convertor would be a great deal easier, if I only could be sure that it won't mess up. So... should I attempt the RTF->HTML road, or should I rather spend my strength in looking for a HTML editor in Delphi 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say either approach is reasonable. Going with the RTF->HTML approach may make it trickier to deal with editing the existing data using a web frontend in the future, however.